# Updating a model from a dictionary object efficiently

Tags: django

I have a simple model:

```
     class A(models.Model):
        status=models.CharField()
```

and I have a list of dictionary items in this way:

```
     data=[
         {'id':1, 'status':'moved'},
         {'id':2, 'status':'sized'}
         ]
```

the id and status keys are related to the model fields. Currently, I am updating them by looping the data and it was ok. But the web service sent a long list the other day and it got me thinking, what if they don't send for days and when they send, it can be a big list. Since i don't have control over the data passed to me, what would be the most efficient way to make the updates?

Currently:

```
       for i in range(len(data)):
           record=A.objects.get(pk=data[i]['id'])
           record.status=data[i]['status']
           record.save()
```

I am looking for something like .filter().update(....) but with status that can apply differently to each record.

Any one?

Comment: Use some task queue and do the updates asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of your code using an [atomic transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def update(data):
    for d in range(data):
        record = A.objects.get(pk=d['id'])
        record.status = d['status']
        record.save()
```

If the process takes too long use some task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) it will do the job in the background or schedule it at any given time for example at midnight when no one uses your app